# bot send msg when someone speaks

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have another question concerning my catch cmd. If I wanted to make it so that it was no longer an activable command but instead had a small chance of triggering when anyone speaks ever, how would I go about that? Would I need to put it in my message.js file? I know if I put it there as is it will trigger every time someone uses a command. However, I don't want it limited to someone using a command and I don't want it to happen every time. I've also heard of putting it in a separate json file and linking it back somehow. Any help is appreciated.

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");

module.exports = {
    name: "catch",
    description: "users must type catch first to catch the animal",
    async execute(client, message, msg, args, cmd, Discord, profileData) {
        
        const prey = [
            "rabbit",
            "rat",
            "bird",
        ];

        const caught = [
            "catch",
        ];

        const chosenPrey = prey.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).slice(0, 1);

        const whenCaught = caught.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).slice(0, 1);

        const filter = ({ content }) => whenCaught.some((caught) => caught.toLowerCase() == content.toLowerCase());

        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({ max: 1, filter, time: 15000 });

        const earnings = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 5;

        collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
            if(m.content?.toLowerCase() === 'catch') {
                           
                const user = m.author;
                const userData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: user.id });
                
                message.channel.send(`${userData.name} caught the ${chosenPrey}! You gained ${earnings} coins.`);
            }

            await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    userID: m.author.id,
                },
                {
                    $inc: {
                        coins: earnings,
                    },
                }
            );
        });

        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if (reason == "time") {
                message.channel.send('Too slow');
            }
        });

        message.channel.send(`Look out, a ${chosenPrey}! Type CATCH before it gets away!`);
    }
}
```

message.js file just in case

```
const profileModel = require("../../models/profileSchema");

const cooldowns = new Map();
module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {

    let profileData;
    try {
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if(!profileData){
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                name: message.member.user.tag,
                userID: message.author.id, 
                serverID: message.guild.id, 
                coins: 0,
            });
            profile.save();
        }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    
    const prefix = '-';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
    if(!command) return;

    if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`Slow down there! You have to wait ${time_left.toFixed(0)} seconds before you can perform ${command.name} again.`);
        }
    }

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, cmd, Discord, profileData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes...that can be possible. In your command handler, create and export a variable with a boolean

Make sure to do this in global scope (outside any function)

```
let canBeActivated = true;
module.exports.getCanBeActivated = function () { return canBeActivated };
module.exports.setCanBeActivated = function(value) { canBeActivated = value };
```

Then, in your command file, import it and check whether it can be activated

```
const { getCanBeActivated, setCanBeActivated } = require("path/to/message.js")

module.exports = {
   ...
   execute(...) { 
       // command wont run
       if(!getCanBeActivated()) return 
}
```

You can make some logic to make the command run if `canBeActivated` is false (like get a random number between 1-100 and if it matches 4 run it).In case you need to change it, just run, `setCanBeActivated`